# Datatbles js no detecta los datos mostrados

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Al momento de querer inicializar una tabla de Datatable js sin ajax no logro que muestre los datos que la vista ya mostró, pongo el siguiente codigo de ejemplo

```
<table id="products-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Puntos</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            <thead>
              @foreach ($products as $product)
              <tr id="registro-{{$product->id}}">
                <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->tipo}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->descripcion}}</td>
                <td>$ {{$product->precio}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->puntos}}</td>
                <td class="acciones">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editar({{$product->id}})"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icono" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar({{$product->id}})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o icono" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </thead>
          </table>
```

Y el JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      oTable = $('#products-table').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
          "columns": [
              {name: 'id'},
              {name: 'nombre'},
              {name: 'tipo'},
              {name: 'descripcion'},
              {name: 'precio'},
              {name: 'puntos'}
          ]
      });
  });
```

Lo que muestra es lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal o que es lo que me falta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer estás agregando un `<thead>` que no necesitas (estarías definiendo como un doble encabzado), en su lugar debería haber un `<tbody>`:

```
<table id="products-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Puntos</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($products as $product)
              <tr id="registro-{{$product->id}}">
                <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->tipo}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->descripcion}}</td>
                <td>$ {{$product->precio}}</td>
                <td>{{$product->puntos}}</td>
                <td class="acciones">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editar({{$product->id}})"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o icono" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar({{$product->id}})"><i class="fa fa-trash-o icono" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Exacto!!!! era eso, muchas gracias Shaz